# Convert PyArray to C/C++-array

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I manage to convert a c-array to a PyArray and then send it to a module.py to perform array operations and then send it back. But how do I convert the PyArray back to a C-array?
I have searched through stackoverflow, github issues and general googling but cant find out.

This is an excpert from my code:

```
float Array[] = { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8 };
float* ptr = Array;
PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
npy_intp dims[1] = {4};
PyObject * py_array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_FLOAT, ptr);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, py_array);
PyObject* pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

How do I now do to convert `pValue` back to a float array?